# Django: custom decorator: session or redirect

Tags: django

I have the following function view and I want to add a parameter, that redirects the user to another page if `request.session.get('order_reference')`is empty. Similar to the `@login_required` Anyone who can help me with that?

```
   def checkout_page(request):
        session_order_reference = request.session.get('order_reference')
```

Comment: Are you planning to use this decorator on multiple views? If it's only one or two, you can simply `return redirect('some:url')` if `session_order_reference` is empty.

Comment: Yes it's actually only in one. Maybe I will just choose that way instead. Keeps my code a bit shorter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following:

```
def custom_decorator(function):
    def _function(request,*args, **kwargs):
        if request.session.get('order_reference') is None:
        # if empty means, empty string
        # if request.session.get('order_reference') is not None\
        # and not request.session.get('order_reference'):
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/your/url/')
        return function(request, *args, **kwargs)
    return _function
```

After setting up your **custom decorator**, decorate your view with it.

```
@custom_decorator
def checkout_page(request):
    return render(request,'template_name.html')
```